# Variables for width in Python format string

Tags: python, string, format

In order to print a header for tabular data, I'd like to use only one format string `line` and one spec for column widths `w1, w2, w3` (or even `w = x, y, z` if possible.)

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/python-printing-lists-as-tabular-data) but `tabulate` etc. don't let me justify things in the column like `format` does.

This approach works:

```
head = 'eggs', 'bacon', 'spam'  
w1, w2, w3 = 8, 7, 10  # column widths  
line = '  {:{ul}>{w1}}  {:{ul}>{w2}}  {:{ul}>{w3}}'  
under = 3 * '='  
print line.format(*head, ul='', w1=w1, w2=w2, w3=w3)  
print line.format(*under, ul='=', w1=w1, w2=w2, w3=w3)
```

Must I have individual names as widths `{w1}`, `{w2}`, ... in the format string? Attempts like `{w[1]}`, `{w[2]}`, give either `KeyError` or `keyword can't be an expression`.

Also I think the `w1=w1, w2=w2, w3=w3` is not very succinct. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why not use a dictionary - `w = {'w1': 8, 'w2': 7, 'w3': 10}` then call `line.format(..., **w)`. You could even build the dictionary dynamically from `[8, 7, 10]` - `w = {'w{}'.format(index): value for index, value in enumerate([8, 7, 10], 1)}`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you! I'll admit I had to study your automatic dict filler for a  bit before I understood. See below also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is jonrsharpe's comment to my OP, worked out so as to visualise what's going on.

```
line = '  {:{ul}>{w1}}  {:{ul}>{w2}}  {:{ul}>{w3}}'
under = 3 * '_'

head = 'sausage', 'rat', 'strawberry tart'

# manual dict 
v = {'w1': 8, 'w2':5, 'w3': 17}
print line.format(*under, ul='_', **v)

# auto dict
widthl = [8, 7, 9]
x = {'w{}'.format(index): value for index, value in enumerate(widthl, 1)}
print line.format(*under, ul='_', **x)
```

The point is that I want to be able to quickly rearrange the header without having to tweak the format string. The `auto dict` meets that requirement very nicely.

As for filling a dict in this way: WOW!

Answer (score 7):

Using the f-string format becomes very easy nowadays.

If you were using

```
print(f'{token:10}')
```

And you want the 10 to be another variable (for example the max length of all the tokens), you would write

```
print(f'{token:{maxTokenLength}}')
```

In other words, enclose the variable within `{}`

---

In your particular case, all you need is this.

```
head = 'eggs', 'bacon', 'spam'  
w1, w2, w3 = 8, 7, 10  # column widths  

print(f'  {head[0]:>{w1}}  {head[1]:>{w2}}  {head[2]:>{w3}}')
print(f'  {"="*w1:>{w1}}  {"="*w2:>{w2}}  {"="*w3:>{w3}}')
```

Which produces

```
      eggs    bacon        spam
  ========  =======  ==========
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `w[0]`, `w[1]`, `w[2]` should work if you defined `w = 8, 7, 10` and passed `w` as keyword argument like below:

```
>>> head = 'eggs', 'bacon', 'spam'
>>> w = 8, 7, 10  # <--- list is also okay
>>> line = '  {:{ul}>{w[0]}}  {:{ul}>{w[1]}}  {:{ul}>{w[2]}}'
>>> under = 3 * '='
>>> print line.format(*head, ul='', w=w)  # <-- pass as a keyword argument
      eggs    bacon        spam
>>> print line.format(*under, ul='=', w=w)  # <-- pass as a keyword argument
  ========  =======  ==========
```